# Complex destroy query

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to come up with some code (other than a RAW sequelize query) that will allow me to delete all but N newest rows of a given model in one transaction/query.

I've tried the naive approach of using `offset` and `order` in the `Model.detroy` method.

````js
Model.destroy({
  order: ["createdAt", "DESC"],
  offset: N,
  where: {
    parentModelId: someId,
  }
})

What I expected is that the code above constructed a query such as:

```sql
DELETE FROM model WHERE "parentModelId" = 'someId' ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC OFFSET N;
````

Instead, the query generated was:

```sql
DELETE FROM model WHERE "parentModelId" = 'someId';
```

Comment: Please post a solution *as answer* and accept it, not as part of the question.

Comment: @deceze Sorry, new to SO. I did as you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just realized the problem is not with Sequelize.js itself, but rather with PostgreSQL no allowing for such query in the first place. The appropiate way to achieve this is via the query:

```sql
DELETE FROM models WHERE is IN (
  SELECT id FROM models WHERE "parentModelId" = 'someId'
    ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC
    OFFSET N
);
```

The only way to do this in Sequelize.js is via a raw query, unfortuantely. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html

Comment: Sequelize could implement it by generating the subquery for us. For example, it already implements `destroy({limit:` by doing exactly that, and it already implements `find({offset:` without limit, we would just need a `destroy({offset: ` without limit.